# I keep getting a IDBObjectStore error while testing my PWA.

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

So I'm developing a PWA uisng an API. I just managed to set up the code to fetch countries from the API and store them in my indexedDB. However I keep getting a "idb.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided." I have tried to read about it bbut it's not clear enough as to what is meant by this exception. here is the code i'm working on:

```js
fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        dataBee.then(db => {
                if (!db) return;

                let txn = db.transaction('countryRecords', 'readwrite');
                let countryStore = txn.objectStore('countryRecords');

                //data is a multi-nested object from the API
                for (let currency in data) {
                    for (let res in data[currency]) {
                        countryStore.put(
                            data[currency],
                            data[currency][res]["currencyId"]
                        );
                    }
                }
                return txn.complete;
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("countries successfully added");
            })

    });
```

Comment: the Error is coming from this code block:  `for (let currency in data) {
                    for (let res in data[currency]) {
                        countryStore.put(
                            data[currency],
                            data[currency][res]["currencyId"]
                        );
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what is this supposed to be doing?

```
                    for (let res in data[currency]) {
                        countryStore.put(
                            data[currency],
                            data[currency][res]["currencyId"]
                        );
                    }
```

Because currently what it's doing is "store data[currency] in my database N times with N different primary keys". That is almost certainly not what you want to do. If you want to be able to look up an entry in the database based on multiple different keys that are stored in an array, use a multiEntry index.

The error is because you are explicitly specifying the primary key (second parameter to `put`) when your object store is expecting the primary key to be present as a property of the data object itself. This is what supplying the `keyPath` parameter to `createObjectStore` does. If your keyPath is "whatever", then it will look in `data[currency].whatever` to find the primary key.

So you could get rid of the error message by changing your code to this:

```
                    for (let res in data[currency]) {
                        countryStore.put(
                            data[currency]
                        );
                    }
```

But that is still almost certainly not what you want to do, because it'll simply write the same data to the database N times with the same primary key, resulting in just one object in the database and a bunch of wasted time writing it repeatedly. If one object in the database is the result you want, you could just do this:

```
                    countryStore.put(data[currency]);
```

And then if you need to query it in different ways, use indexes.

Comment: aha!! indexes. What i'd like to do is store different data with different primary key. Meaning different objects. this code: for (let res in data[currency]) {
                        countryStore.put(
                            data[currency],
                            data[currency][res]["currencyId"]
                        );
                    } should give me the unique country and a unique country ID everytime I loop through it.